# A box contains $10$ blue marbles and $2$ red marbles. $5$ marbles are drawn at random with replacement.

Tags: probability

What is the chance that both the red marbles will be drawn?

Is my solution correct?

$$ \frac{{2 \choose 2} \cdot {10 \choose 3}}{{12 \choose 5}}\ $$

${2 \choose 2}$ for the number of ways to arrange $2$ red marbles, ${10 \choose 3}$ for number of ways to choose $3$ blue marbles over the total number of ways to choose $5$ marbles.

Comment: Your solution would be correct if we did not replace the marbles.

Comment: Is it a general rule of thumb that when we deal with combination and permutation it's always without replacement?

Comment: @GrahamKemp We wish to get both red marbles separately, so why is it not multinomial?

Comment: Not exactly.  However, the count of successes among a sample drawn *without replacement* from a population *is* definitely a hypergeometric distributed random variable, and that is the probability mass function for such.  What you seek is the probability mass function for the count of successes among samples drawn *with replacement*; and that count is a *binomially distributed* random variable. If we consider the red marbles to be distinct, this will actually be a *multinomial distribution.*

Comment: Yes... That works better. @Remy.

Comment: Also ... $\mathsf P(X_1{\geq}1, X_2{\geq}1)= 1-\mathsf P(X_1{=}0)-\mathsf P(X_2{=}0)+\mathsf P(X_1{=}0,X_2{=}0)$

Comment: Good point, that is a much more efficient approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X_1$ denote the number of times we draw the first red marble, $X_2$ the number of times we draw the second red marble, and $X_3$ be the number of times we draw a blue marble. We wish to find $$P(X_1 \geq 1, X_2 \geq 1)$$

Notice that since we're dealing with successes of more than one category, and we are replacing the marbles, that this is a multinomial distribution:

$$P(X_1=x_1, X_2=x_2, X_3=x_3)=\frac{n!}{x_1!\cdot x_2!\cdot x_3!}\cdot p_1^{x_1}\cdot p_2^{x_2}\cdot p_3^{x_3}$$

where $$p_1=p_2=\frac{1}{12}, p_3=\frac{5}{6}$$

You must sum for all possible values of $x_1,x_2,x_3$ which satisfy the criteria, and you should find there are $10$ viable combinations.

I would suggest making these calculations in excel. As a check of your work, I will give you that an R simulation gives a probability of roughly $0.107$ which agrees with the analytical result I obtained.

```
coin=c(rep("B",10),"RedOne","RedTwo")
u=replicate(10^6,sample(coin,5,repl=T))
blue = colSums(u=="B")
redone =colSums(u=="RedOne")
redtwo=colSums(u=="RedTwo")
mean(redone >= 1 & redtwo >= 1) 

[1] 0.107308
```

Comment: No spreadsheeting needed: $\mathsf P(X_1{\geq}1, X_2{\geq}1)~{=1-\mathsf P(X_1{=}0\cup X_2{=}0)\\= 1-\mathsf P(X_1{=}0)-\mathsf P(X_2{=}0)+\mathsf P(X_1{=}0,X_2{=}0)}$

Comment: Thanks, yes, @GrahamKemp's approach is much more efficient and I suggest you use his method.

Comment: Wow, Thank you guys for such an exhaustive explanations! I'm going to take some time to digest these.

Comment: You might also want to confirm that we are indeed dealing with replacement.

Comment: @Remy yes we are dealing with replacement in this question